# Unable to query custom article type through apex

Tags: community, knowledge, articles

```
public without sharing class COMM_Articles {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<COMM_Releases__kav> getFeaturesData(){         
        List<COMM_Releases__kav> communityArticlesList = [
            SELECT Release_date_of_feature__c, Short_description_of_feature__c,Long_description_of_feature__c
            FROM COMM_Releases__kav 
            WITH DATA CATEGORY SF_Help_Desk__c 
            AT (CommunityReleaseHome__c,CommunityReleaseFeature__c,CommunityReleaseTeaser__c)
        ];    
        System.debug('communityArticlesList.size:' + communityArticlesList.size());
        return communityArticlesList;
    }
}
```

> I am able to query data from Dev console, workbench, anonymous window
>   but not apex.

I gave access to this object in the profile.
Data categories have All Access

even simple `select id from comm_releases__kav` is not returning anything from apex

anyone had the same issue?

Comment: not returning anything meaning 0 results,  or you get an error?

Comment: 0 results retrieved

Comment: sounds like a permission issue to me, check [Using SOQL to Determine Your Force.com User’s Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)

Comment: permissions seems fine too....

Comment: how are you calling your method, and from where? as the same user?

Comment: yes as the same user. calling it from lightning comonent.

Comment: I didn't enable Parter/Customer/Public Knowledge Base checkboxes for channels. It works fine once i enable for all channels i need.

Comment: you might want to add the answer and mark it as resolved in 48 hrs,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't enable Parter/Customer/Public Knowledge Base checkboxes for channels. It works fine once i enable for all channels i need. 
Thanks @glls